# The titles of my articles are not indexed on google

Tags: seo, articles

My site is istorikathemata.com a Greek history site and has been founded at 2009. In the last year roughly google search engine has stopped displaying my articles. I create an article, publish it in my site, and although I am the creator of it, but in the search engine I see only the sites which have copy it. I think this not fair. An example:  https://www.istorikathemata.com/2019/07/19-1924.html (In greek: Το κίνημα του υποστράτηγου Χαράλαμπου Λούφα και τα Δημοκρατικά Τάγματα (19 Νοεμβρίου 1924). I have not changed any preferences on my site, I use an official template of blogger, I publish original content in ratio 5 to 1. I am very sad about this development,  would like an answer why my site is omitted.

Comment: When you say "titles of articles are not indexed" do you mean that Google is showing something else in place of your titles in the search results, or do you mean that Google isn't indexing the article from your site at all?

Comment: For one, your URL is not very friendly. 19-1924.html is not very descriptive, and although this is not crucial it would help if you would add the keyword you are trying to rank for.
Your robots.txt looks weird, and it's blocking all /search/. It looks like you are trying to hide all the dynamic pages, but on the other hand your are having them displayed as categories. I would go with simple Allow: *.
Try shortening your titles below 70 chars.
Add lang="el" (or variant) to the html start tag.

Comment: Thank you both for your effort to help. What I mean Stephen is that I had written the article and published it but when you search the Greek title my site is not displyed. It is omitted.

Comment: Mnea I changed the robot .txt to what you advised (Allow:*). Do you think that the problemcould be that I used http and not https? I changed to https on Saturday...